# spatial data distance search - optimization options

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, spatial

Our business user loves for our searches to be done by distance, problem is we have over 1 million records with a lat/long location. We are using SQL 2008 but we keep running into issues when we order or restrict our searches by distance that the queries take way to long (30 seconds plus). This is unacceptable, there has got to be a better way to do this. We have done everything we can with SQL 2008 and want to upgrade to 2012 if we can at some point.

I ask though, if there is another technology or optimization that we could apply. Could we switch to a different DB for faster performance, a different search algorithm to apply, estimation algorithm, tree, grids, pre-computation, etc?

Comment: Question, are you currently using the spatial indexing that is available in SQLServer 2008?

Comment: Yes, we have gone back and forth on the grid densities and have verified the index is being used (also using the with(index hint). We can apply a general filter quick, but as soon as we do a distance order by we lose all performance, which seems to be the most common complaint.

Comment: Does this performance loss happens if you do the order by distance after your filter limits the rows returned to say, 500-1000?

Comment: It seems to happen if the initial search area from the primarty mssql filter returns a large number of results (like any metropolitan). We have seen MSSQL choke on 200 records before taking well over 30 seconds.

Comment: This site provides an excellent method to efficiently search for coordinates within a given distance: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Answer (score 0):

A solution that might be useful here would be to break your search into two parts:

1) Run a query where you find all records that are within a certain value + or - of the current lat/lng of your location, the where clause might look like:

where (@latitude > (lat - .001) and @latitude > (lat - .001)) and (@longitude> (lng- .001) and @longitude> (longitude- .001))

Using this approach, and especially with an index on both the latitude and longitude columns, you can very quickly define a working set of locations within a specified distance.

2) with the rough results from step 1, use the great circle/haversine method to determine what the actual distance between the source location and each point is.

Where this approach falls over is if there is never any limit to the radius that you are searching, but it works great if you are for instance looking to find all locations within a specific distance of a given point.

Comment: The primary filter for the spatial indexing does this pretty quickly, its just the distance part that seems to freak out.

Comment: How are you doing the great circle calculation?

Comment: STDistance, the built in function for MSSQL 2008 for spatial data. I created my own function, and even simplified the calculation (with errors) but didn't have any luck in speeding it up.